# Making a simple grid/dotted line of specific length

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, line, vector-grid

My boss went out to the field and forgot her GPS unit. Using an anchor point and a compass, she paced out to different points and took soil samples. I have the basemap up with the exact location of her anchor point. I am stuck though.

What I want to do is proceed due west from the anchor point, 25m, then put a marker. Then I want to proceed another 25m, then another, etc., while putting markers. Then I want to go due south in the same pattern, back east, then south, then west... you get the idea.

I need to mark where she went on a basemap as accurately as possibly (i.e., type 25m west and then a dot appears).

Comment: welcome to GIS se. Please mention the software that you are using because the solution depends on the software. Furthermore, try to have only one question per post (here you have 2).

Comment: Will totally depend on what kind of GPS unit and software you have available. Please provide more details!

Comment: Did not use GPS unit. I'm not really concerned with that. Using ArcMap 10.4.1

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize I asked 2 questions- I thought that maybe one would be the answer for the other.

Comment: Also note that your grid squares are each 625m² (ie, 25m x 25m). You could call them (25m)² squares.

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to try and make the single question that you want to ask clearer. I suspect the tool that you are looking for is Create Fishnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure your ArcMap dataframe is in a projected coordinate system and your map units are in metres.
2. Create a point file with the location of your boss' starting point.
3. Create a new line file, and start editing.
4. In the Create Features tab, select your new line layer, and then select the Line construction tool.
5. Make sure you have set up snapping to your point file, then click on your boss' start point.
6. The line construction should start. Then right-click any blank area in the dataframe and select Direction / Length (Ctrl-G).
7. Enter the bearing and distance your boss moved to her first point (having consideration for your Angular Units settings in the Editing Options window - North Azimuth, Polar etc) and press Enter.
8. Continue plotting all points in this manner. When all points are plotted, stop editing and save your edits.
9. From *ArcToolbox > Data Management Tools > Features* double-click on the *Feature Vertices To Points* tool.
10. Select your newly completed line file as the input features, specify and output feature class, and leave the Point Type as All, then click OK to run the tool.
11. The resulting point layer should contain points at each location your boss stopped for samples.

When you're done, get your boss to make sure she has a GPS capable phone, so that if she forgets the GPS again, she can just take geolocated photos at each sample point to save you encountering this problem again!